# Matrix Multiplication with Mex file

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm having trouble with the multiplication of two matrix using mex files in Matlab with C.
I'm compiling the next code but when I call the function, Matlab crahses:

```
#include "mex.h"

void Multipl(double **a, double **b, double **res, mwSize n)
{
 mwSize i;
 mwSize j;
 mwSize k;

 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
        res[i][j]=0;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){
            res[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];;
        }
    }
   }
  }
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
size_t ncols;                   /* size of matrix */
mxArray *mx, *my;
double *pr, *qr;
int *sr;
mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(2,3,mxREAL);
pr = mxGetPr(mx); // pointer to first double element of mx
qr = (double *)mxGetData(mx); // pointer to first double element of mx
my = mxCreateNumericMatrix(2,3,mxINT32_CLASS,mxREAL);
sr = (int *)mxGetData(my); // pointer to first int element of my
ncols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,(mwSize)ncols,mxREAL);
int* outMatrix         = (int *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
/* call the computational routine */
Multipl(mx,my,outMatrix,(mwSize)ncols);
```

}

What should I change in this code??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't mx and my both 2x3 matrices?  And the output buffer is 1x??

Comment: So many issues with your code... casting int* to double**, casting mxArray* to double**, using uninitialized memory, using a 1xn matrix as if it were nxn, ... Turn on warnings when compiling, then fix your code until you have 0 warnings. That should fix at least the wrong pointer casting.

Comment: Also you can't take a simple data pointer and start using the [ ][ ] syntax with it.  It takes some extra steps to use this syntax.  See here for some example code: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/309434-matlab-crashing-when-evaluating-mex?s_tid=srchtitle